# BEGINNER: Removing items from Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, random, duplicates

I am coding a random quote generator. I almost have it fully coded how I want. I am a beginner in HTML and I've never used Javascript before this weekend. I took from multiple tutorials to code this exactly how I want it and am very proud.  I have one last thing I am trying to do. When a item from the array is called, I want it to be removed, stored in another array and when the original array reaches 0, I want it to reset. I know its possible but I am not sure what to add to this script to make it work. Thanks so much for any help.

```js
const quotes = [{
    game: 'CARD TYPE 1',
    quote: "This is the card description for Card Type 1",
    rule: "Card Type 1 Rules"
  },
  {
    game: 'CARD TYPE 2',
    quote: "This is the card description for Card Type 2",
    rule: "Card Type 2 Rules"
  },
  {
    game: 'CARD TYPE 3',
    quote: "This is the card description for Card Type 3",
    rule: "Card Type 3 Rules"
  }
];

const maincontainer = document.querySelector("#quoteBtn");
const questionStyle = document.querySelector("#quote");
const gameTitleStyle = document.querySelector("#gameTitle");
const ruleStyle = document.querySelector("#ruleTxt");

quoteBtn.addEventListener("click", displayQuote);

function displayQuote() {
  let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);

  gameTitle.innerHTML = quotes[number].game;
  quote.innerHTML = quotes[number].quote;
  ruleTxt.innerHTML = quotes[number].rule;
}
```

```html
<style type="text/css">
  body {
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    background-color: #3F6BFF;
  }
  
  .maincontainer {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    animation: flip 1s;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 25px;
  }
  
  .thecard {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    border-radius: 25px;
  }
  
  .thecard:active {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
  
  .thefront {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    border-radius: 25px;
  }
  
  .theback {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 25px;
  }
  
  .gameTitleStyle {
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 32px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  
  .ruleStyle {
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
    font-style: italic;
  }
  
  .questionStyle {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <div class="maincontainer" id="quoteBtn">

    <div class="thecard">

      <div class="thefront">
        <h1 class="gameTitleStyle" id="gameTitle">Business Name</h1>
        <p class="ruleStyle" id="ruleTxt">Rules</p>
        <p class="questionStyle" id="quote">Card Description</p>
      </div>

      <div class="theback"></div>

    </div>


  </div>


</body>
```

Comment: Look at [pop(), push(), shift() and unshift()](https://alligator.io/js/push-pop-shift-unshift-array-methods/) operators for arrays

Comment: @RachelGallen Thanks. Im trying to figure that out now. Whenever I add on to my code I get confused. #LearningAsIGo

Comment: It's always like that when you start to learn something new; gets easier as you go along! Remember you can copy your array to another var  ( like var arr1 = arr; ) if you want to  reset easily.

Answer (score 1):

Removing an element from an array can be done with the [Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method. For example, this removes element 2 from an array called "items", and returns the removed element in a new array:

```
let removedItems = items.splice(2);
```

Add items to an array using [Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

```
otherArray.push(...removedItems);
```

The `...removedItems` converts the removedItems array to a list of items. The `...` is called the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

These should be enough to accomplish what you want.

Comment: I will look into this. It takes me a while to figure out how I fit these things into what I have. Thanks for the response